# SSHFS from Android to NAS

Tags: mount, ssh

I'm trying to get any folder on the internal storage of a HTC M7 to be mounted via `sshfs` to a folder on my NAS. The goal would be to have for example the `/sdcard/My Documents/My Recordings` folder setup like this so it has almost unlimited storage. I've installed [EasySSHFS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.nsu.bobrofon.easysshfs) and connected via `adb shell`. In `/data/data/ru.nsu.bobrofon.easysshfs/files` are the `ssh` and `sshfs` binaries. I exported this folder to `$PATH` and started trying.

I tried mounting through the following symlinks:

```
/sdcard 
/storage/emulated/0
/storage/emulated/legacy
/mnt/shell/emulated/0
/mnt/shell/emulated/legacy
```

always trying to get to the `My Documents/My Recordings` folder.
Depending on whether or not I used `su` some folder paths worked others don't.
But even if they where mounted the app (I tried with [Smart Voice Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andrwq.recorder) as it allows you to set the path of your recordings, HTC's builtin Voice Recorder doesn't) wouldn't place its files onto the NAS but instead into the folder. Using a different path I was able to see the files locally.
Without `su` though I can't `sshfs` because of a permission problem with `/dev/fuse`.
I think the problem must be with the way android mounts the sdcard (`fuse`) but I can't figure out what exactly it is. I also tried mounting something not on the sdcard and symlinking to it but that didn't work either. Im suspecting the fuse mount to prohibit that as well.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to disable "Mount namespace separation" in SuperSU to get this to work.